# How to read JSON data in laravel controller?

Tags: json, laravel, controller

Before this, I was getting 405 methods not allowed error in live server

ajax call to upload files:

```
$('#form-repeater').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } });


let thiss=$(this);


let form = document.getElementById('form-repeater');
let data =new FormData(form);


$.ajax({

        type:thiss.attr('method'),
        url:thiss.attr('action'),
        data:data,
        dataType:'JSON',
        // ContentType:'application/json',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(response){
            if(response.message=='1'){

                    Swal.fire(
                    'Product Added Successfully',
                    '',
                    'success'
                    )
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.href="/banner";
                    }, 2000);//wait 2 seconds

                }
            else{


                  error = response.errors;
                  if(error.staff){
                      $('#form-repeater .invalid-staff').html(error.staff);
                    }else{
                        $('#form-repeater .invalid-staff').html('');                            
                    }

                if(error.customerNumber){                            
                        $('#form-repeater .invalid-cust_numb').html(error.customerNumber);
                     }else{
                        $('#form-repeater .invalid-cust_numb').html('');
                  }}});
```

This is my response from ajax call:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNkmV.jpg)
normally I can't retrieve data in my controller:

I debug using `dd($request->all());`

Answer (score 0):

When sending JSON requests to your application, you may access the JSON data via the `input` method as long as the `Content-Type` header of the request is properly set to `application/json`. You may even use "dot" syntax to dig into JSON arrays: `$name = $request->input('user.name');`

Then on your controller you could do something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a new user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('user.name');

        // Manage your data the way you want
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't understand could you please explain a bit more...please can you solve above controller data

Comment: I've edited my answer, please take a look. If you need it to be more adapted to your needs you have to edit your question and give more details of how you are sending the request to the application and what exactly you are receiving by doing a `dd()`